# CLion can't show accents and "ñ "

Tags: c++, windows, jetbrains-ide, spanish

When I compile a code with a text in Spanish the accents always show like weird symbols. The file encoding is UTF-8 and the editor is configured in Spanish also.

The code:

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
int main(){
    printf("niño á é í ó ú");
    return 0;
};
```

Output in the terminal:

```text
ni├▒o ├í ├® ├¡ ├│ ├║
```

[image]

Please tell me if it is possible to change this, it's too annoying.

I've change the file encoding and the editor language and nothing works.

OS: Windows

Comment: Post code as text not as image

Comment: Could you maybe give us the exact output of the following code, so that we can see exactly what data values are being sent to the terminal/console? `char test[] = "niño á é í ó ú"; for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof test; i++ ) printf( "%d\n", test[i] );`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel the result is '110
105
-61
-79
111
32
-61
-95
32
-61
-87
32
-61
-83
32
-61
-77
32
-61
-70
0'

Comment: Could you please change `printf( "%d\n", test[i] );` to `printf( "%02X\n", (unsigned char)test[i] );` That way, it will be hexadecimal and positive, which will probably be more useful.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel yep that's give me positives numbers ' 110
105
195
177
111
32
195
161
32
195
169
32
195
173
32
195
179
32
195
186
0 '

Comment: @EmilioHernández: Meanwhile, I have edited my comment to make it hexadecimal, but it doesn't matter. That is already very interesting information. It confirms that your program is indeed sending UTF-8 to your terminal/console. This means that the problem is not your program, but the way your terminal/console is interpreting the data.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel so... there's a way to change it??

Comment: I suggest that you try using the function call `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);` as described in the question to which I linked above. Note that you will have to `#include <Windows.h>` to use that function.

Comment: I believe all you must do is to put the line `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);` immediately above the line `printf("niño á é í ó ú");` and add `#include <Windows.h>` to your program.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel yep that's work but if is the only ways to resolved that I take it, thank you for you time, but i guess i'll change ide cause is annoying

Comment: @EmilioHernández: I don't think it is a problem of your IDE, but rather of the Windows Console. Other IDEs will likely have the same problem.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel it's weird VsCode works good and other like Sublime text 4, this is my first time typing a question how i can thank for answer me?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel yep thank you so so much I'm really grateful for your help <3

Comment: I am not familiar with VSCode or Sublime text, but it is possible that these IDEs automatically set the Console into UTF-8 mode. You may want to take a look at the settings of those IDEs, and maybe also take a look whether CLion offers any such settings.